# Why can't OLS estimates be used to obtain regression parameters when dealing with high dimensional data?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, overfitting, unbiased-estimator

Suppose I have a data set consisting of $n$ observations: ${\displaystyle \left\{\mathbf {x} _{i},y_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{n}}$.

If I apply linear regression :${\displaystyle \mathbf {y} =\mathrm {X} {\boldsymbol {\beta }}+{\boldsymbol {\varepsilon }},\,}$

where
${\displaystyle \mathrm {X} ={\begin{bmatrix}X_{11}&X_{12}&\cdots &X_{1p}\\X_{21}&X_{22}&\cdots &X_{2p}\\\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\X_{n1}&X_{n2}&\cdots &X_{np}\end{bmatrix}},\qquad {\boldsymbol {\beta }}={\begin{bmatrix}\beta _{1}\\\beta _{2}\\\vdots \\\beta _{p}\end{bmatrix}},\qquad \mathbf {y} ={\begin{bmatrix}y_{1}\\y_{2}\\\vdots \\y_{n}\end{bmatrix}}.}$

Given that $p>>n$ how can I explain that the OLS method is not appropriate?

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way to see this is that you can't even _compute_ $\hat{\beta}$ when $p > n-1$ due to a matrix singularity.  Also consider that if $p = n-1$ you will get a fit, and the $R^2$ will be 1.0 no matter what $y$ is --- even if you randomly permute $y$.

Comment: @FrankHarrell isn't it when p=n. E.g. if you have two data points (n=2) and estimate with the mean (p=1) then the R^2 does not need to be 1 because there will be non-zero residuals. (or does p not include the intercept/mean term?).

Comment: p does not include the intercept.